# Linq To SQL - compare two dates in two different formats

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm trying to compare two dates that are in two different formats:

```
       var messages = (from m in db.ChatMessages
                        where m.RoomID == roomID &&
                        m.MessageID > messageID &&
                        m.MessageTime > timeUserJoined.AddSeconds(1)
                        orderby m.MessageTime ascending
                        select new { m.MessageID, m.Text, m.User.username, m.MessageTime, m.Color });
```

My problem is  that my Database tables stored DateTime fields in the US format i.e. 12/24/2011 1:35:11 PM. So in the query above, the line *m.MessageTime > timeUserJoined.AddSeconds(1)* might be 12/24/2011 1:35:11 PM > 24/12/2011 13:35:11 PM

How do I get around this - comparing two dates in two different formats and what are the best practices?

At the mment i'm not getting any records back, I think because of these comparison issues?

Many Thanks :)

Comment: I doubt that the format of `DateTime` has anything to do with your problem. Use [Linq2Sql visualizer](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/31/linq-to-sql-debug-visualizer.aspx) to get SQL query, and see if it looks like the SQL you'd expect.

Answer (score 2):

You state they are DateTime fields... Then good news; DateTime in .NET and TSQL **does not have** any format - it is just a number. Any particular format you are seeing exists only in the imagination of your IDE or other tools (SSMS etc).

As long as it is DateTime you won't have a problem here.

Comment: Exactly right.  In fact, in Linq to SQL this gets translated into a SQL query.  And SQL will compare these using its native formatting and operations, regardless of its particular presentation format in your app.

Answer (score 0):

First, I believe you should be using DateTime.CompareTo() to compare your timestamps.

Second, how are you consuming the messages collection? Are you aware that it's a collection of anonymous, untyped objects?

(I'd comment, but I don't have the rep)

Comment: I disagree on CompareTo: `>` is fine, and much more readable IMO.